# "Else" equivalent in foreach loop when ienumerable is empty

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, ienumerable

Assuming the ienumerable is not null, a foreach loop simply won't execute if that ienumerable is empty.  But instead, I need to run other code if the collection is empty.  Here's sample code which works flawlessly:

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>() {};

if (theList.Count > 0) {
    foreach (var item in theList) {
       //do stuff
    }
} else {
    //throw exception or do whatever else
}
```

Is there anyway to shorten this up via out-of-the-box C#, an Extension Method, etc?  In my head I was thinking the following would be cool, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>() {};

foreach (var item in theList) {
   //do stuff
} else {
    //throw exception or do whatever else
}
```

EDIT: My solution thanks to insight from Maarten:  The following will throw an exception if the collection is null or empty (if you want to simply **ignore** cases where the collection is null or empty, use a ternary operator in the foreach)

```
static class Extension {
    public static IEnumerable<T> FailIfNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        if (collection == null || !collection.Any())
            throw new Exception("Collection is null or empty");

        return collection;
    }
}

class Program {
    List<string> theList = new List<string>() { "a" };

    foreach (var item in theList.FailIfNullOrEmpty()) {
        //do stuff                    
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing exceptions like this. An empty `List` is not an exception.

Comment: Why do you need to throw an exception for this? You could shorten it to `theList.Any()` so it doesn't need to iterate through the entire list.

Comment: For the sake of my code, an empty List is an exception.  But I will update my post because I don't want that to be the focus of this question.

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your question but there is a difference between null value and empty list. shouldn't you check if list != null instead?

Comment: Technically yes, but for simplicity in asking this question and sample code I am assuming it's not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to achieve this, you could create an extension method (like you said yourself).

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in data.FailIfEmpty(new Exception("List is empty"))) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> FailIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Exception exception) {
        if (!collection.Any()) {
            throw exception;
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  I know in my question I am assuming the collection is not null but I will add additional logic in the FailIfEmpty method to check for nulls.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the exception beforehand, without having to write the `else` block:

```
if(mylist.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception("Test");

foreach(var currItem in mylist)
    currItem.DoStuff();
```

The execution flow won't reach the loop if the exception has been raised.